# How to check if values in two columns has the same class in R?

Tags: r, class, if-statement

I have to check if a value in two columns or lists has the same class. I wrote the following codes but none are working because just write the last value on the list but not only the first values.

#### My lists

```
x <- c(1,3,6,2) ## All are numeric
y <- c(6,4,3,'a') ## Note that is a string at here
m <- NULL
```

### Code 1

```
for (i in length(x)) {
  if (class(x[i]) == class(y[i])) m[i] <-'ok' else m[i] <- 'no ok'
}
```

### Code 2

```
et <-function(x, y){
  for (i in length(x)) {
    if (class(x[i]) == class(y[i])) {
      m[i] = 'ok'
    } else {
      m[i] = 'not ok'
    }
    return(f)
  }
}
et(x,y)
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: All the elements in an atomic vector have the same class. So `class(x) == class(y)` should be fine. Or if you mean a list then it should be `x <- list(1,3,6,2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check the class of corresponding elements in two lists, you can use `Map` function:

```
x <- list(1,3,6,2)   
y <- list(6,4,3,'a')
Map(function(x,y) c("no ok", "ok")[as.integer(class(x) == class(y)) + 1], x, y)
[[1]]
[1] "ok"

[[2]]
[1] "ok"

[[3]]
[1] "ok"

[[4]]
[1] "no ok"
```

Or `mapply` which returns a vector:

```
mapply(function(x,y) c("no ok", "ok")[as.integer(class(x) == class(y)) + 1], x, y)
[1] "ok"    "ok"    "ok"    "no ok"
```

Comment: Cool use of `Map` and `mapply`: I rarely see those!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in the for loop call, which is only passing one integer to run, rather than a list of integers, like you're hoping. Change this:

```
for (i in length(x)) { ...
```

to this:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) { ...
```

Notice that "length(x)" is 4, whereas "1:length(x)" is all integers 1:4.

Answer (score 0):

We can also loop through using `lapply/sapply` and get a logical output

```
 sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) class(x[[i]])==class(y[[i]]))
```

#### data

```
x <- list(1,3,6,2)   
y <- list(6,4,3,'a')
```